# createthread MFC dialog based app (Syntax)

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, dialog

I am trying to create a Worker thread but I have not done Visual C++ since 2004 and threading syntax has changed (Please don't worry about timing issues, I will have that covered). the issue is that in an MFC dialog app, every way I know of trying to create a thread won't get past the compiler. I also have tried the "&" trick. It can't seem to find this function at all. Can anyone help please? NOTE: I tried three methods and I left the first uncommented.

```
    if (i_found >= 0) { //this is just a combobox snippet to show the calls
        MessageBox(wch.GetBuffer(0), L"Port Select", MB_OK);
        _serialPort->Close();
        ConversationRight = gcnew Conversation(systrName);
        _beginthread(&CDLP_Printer_ControlDlg::Mine_QL, 0, 0); //NONE WORKING!!
        //unsigned long lpRecvThread = _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, Mine_QL, (void*)this, NULL, NULL);
        //unsigned long lpThreadIdRequest;
        //::CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Mine_QL, (void*)NULL, 0, &lpThreadIdRequest);
    }
    else
        MessageBox(L"Not the left board", L"Port Select", MB_OK);

    _serialPort->Close();
}


void CDLP_Printer_ControlDlg::OnBnClickedBtnStop()
{
    ConversationRight->WriteLn("5");
}


bool CDLP_Printer_ControlDlg::UpdateCommsWindow_left(String^ strCommsLine)
{
    return false;
}

void  CDLP_Printer_ControlDlg::Mine_QL()
{


    //_endthread();
}
```

Comment: You can't use a member function as a thread proc.  You can however use a static member function as the thread proc and pass `this` through as one of the `createThread` parameters. This is not portable but enough Windows code does it.  Cast it back to a pointer to the class inside the static member function and using to call member function(s) of the class.

Comment: Relevant [The Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040109-00/?p=41133/)

Comment: The threadproc signature and syntax haven't changed in decades, literally. `CreateThread` expects a function with `__stdcall`, you cannot pass a function with `__thiscall` calling convention.

Comment: Thanks guys. I can not have a static member function of a Dialog though. Its specifically not allowed, I tried to remove the scope identifiers but its an unresolved external.

Comment: If you cannot have a static class member, then you won't have a thread calling a class member. I'm pretty convinced, that *"You cannot have a static class member"* is not part of your specification.